# How to show details for installed application on Android?

Tags: android

I am writing an app for listing applications installed on the system. I am using PackageManager and queryIntentActivities() to get list of applications.

I am able to start it, uninstall it (using ACTION_DELETE), but I have no idea how to show details (where user can force stop, move to/from SD card, see disk space usage etc)?

I tried ACTION_VIEW, but it also shows uninstall dialog on 2.1 (did not check other versions yet). I also didn't find anything except for an unanswered question on android-dev mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with API Level 9 (a.k.a., Android 2.3), you should be able to use [`ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS) for this. There is no way to get to this screen in previous versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks, this does work for 2.3. However, I noticed apps like Advanced Task Manager can do it on 2.2 (probably also lower). So I suppose it can be done using this way for >= 2.3 and in some form of hack for previous versions.

Answer (score 9):

Solution combined with answer above and http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/1d4607eb370b1fe6/3cd4b85c310fe112?show_docid=3cd4b85c310fe112&pli=1:

```
    Intent intent;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        /* on 2.3 and newer, use APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS with proper URI */
        Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:" + pkgName);
        intent = new Intent("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS", packageURI);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }  else  {
        /* on older Androids, use trick to show app details */
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
        intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.InstalledAppDetails"); 
        intent.putExtra("com.android.settings.ApplicationPkgName", pkgName); 
        intent.putExtra("pkg", pkgName); 
        ctx.startActivity(intent);          
    }
```

Comment: This `on older Androids` part of the code gives me a exception when I try to run it forced (on 2.3). `unable to find explicit activity class`

Comment: Nevermind, on 2.2 it does run. Apparently that code path doesn't work on 2.3+, but does on 2.2-.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void openAppInfo(Context context, String packageName)
{
    try 
    {
        //Open the specific App Info page:
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } 
    catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e ) 
    {
        //Open the generic Apps page:
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```